# Display model of ApplicationController in a nested template in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to show the user-profile of the user after login. So i figured I'll make the Application.Controller an ObjectController and set it's model property to the user-object.
The problem I'm having right now is that I don't know how to show the user-properties in the nested profile template?
I actually saw other answers on SO using {{#each todo in App.todosController.content}}. but that only works for an ArrayController. Maybe this is only possible with an ArrayController, I really don't know, but that would be strange. Thanks for any help!

To test this I'm setting the model of the Application.Controller to the user-object when login is succesful.
Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="profile">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-padded">
                <div>
                    <p><h3>Username: {{{user.username}}}</h3><p>
                    <p>trials: {{user.trials}}</p>
                    <p>results: {{user.results}}</p>
                    <p>email: {{user.email}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>

App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('signup');
this.resource('login');
this.resource('profile');
this.resource('practice');
this.resource('overview');
});

App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    model: {},
    needs: ['application'],
    loggedInUser: {id: 9, 
    username: "rooty", 
    trials: "fghsds", 
    results: "fdfsd", 
    email: "dsefs@ds.com"},
    loginHandler: function(data) {
        // sign in logic
        this.set("controllers.application.isLoggedIn", true);
        this.set("controllers.application.model", loggedInUser);
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isLoggedIn: false
});
```

The user-object looks like this:

```
User {id: 9, 
        username: "rooty", 
        trials: "fghsds", 
        results: "fdfsd", 
        email: "dsefs@ds.com"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close! So your login controller sets the model on the application controller. Your controller's Login Controller's `needs` property means that all properties on the scope of the Application controller will be available to your Login controller. Following that logic, couldn't your profile controller also `needs: ['application']`?

With a little work, we can call refer to users like you'd like from your profile controller:

```
needs: ['application'],
users: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.model')
```

Then in your profile template, what you already have should work:

```
<div>
  <p><h3>Username: {{{user.username}}}</h3><p>
  <p>trials: {{user.trials}}</p>
  <p>results: {{user.results}}</p>
  <p>email: {{user.email}}</p>
</div>
```

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tobomoranudu/1/)

Notice in the JSBin that on the index controller, I have a computed alias for the applications model. The input helper's value in the index template is bound to this computed alias, aka the application's model. Observe in the application template that I only use `{{model}}`. As you type in the input, you see the model change thanks to Ember's powerful binding so we've definitely targeted the application model via the `needs` and computed alias.

Same thing with the profile template.

Comment: Tanx sunrize920! That worked like a charm. The needs: 
['application'] I figured out on my own, however this use of 
Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.model') is new to me.. 
I apparently didn't take full advantage of their functionality. So I'm very glad to learn all this!